# How Can i read sql files in UNIX line by line through command?

Tags: unix

I have a .sql file, and I have to change the statements in that file and want to replace that sql file in sh file.Can anyone help me??

Comment: Without rather more information, it's hard to give good advice. Why are you mean by "replace that sql file in sh file". Can you give some examples of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Suppose i have a line in .sql file is 

SELECT * FROM TABLE

But i want to replace it as 

mysql -uroot -pxxx ABD -e "SELECT  FROM TABLE";

Can you please help me to achive it.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just importing the sql file using
 
mysql -u root -pxxx my_db_name < sqlfile.sql

Comment: yes actually sometime, when i have a 50000 of records in my sequel file, and because of any reason if there is a problem in a single statement in the mid of file then it will stop the  execution of entire process.So that's the main reason to create sperately. Hope you can understand.

Comment: If you investigate you will probably find your RDBMS has an error handling mechanism when dealing with very large input files. Certainly Oracle had mechanisms over 20 years ago that allowed processes to continue and any odd lines to get logged to deal with later. That might be a better route than my direct answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways of doing this.

I'd probably pick a text editor that can do search and replace and deal with large files. Then ask it to search for

> SELECT

and replace with

> mysql -uroot -pxxx ABD -e "SELECT

Then replace each table name with the same table name with a " added.

Save it as a .sh file and then you have what you need.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I did it by using Perl Script.